# Monitor JIRA Tomcat Servers remotely

Tags: tomcat, jira, jira-plugin

I'm evaluating the JIRA system with plug-ins Fisheye/Cruciable on my office desktop computer (WinXP). Evaluation is going well and it looks like we will move it to a local net server. A peculiarity with JIRA and Fisheye (both running on their own Tomcat servers) is being able to tell when both servers are up and running. I would like to write an app similar to the XAMPP control panel which will allow our users to see if the system is running or not. Right now all we see is a 404 error if a server is not running properly. Is there an open source monitoring app, or some existing code that I can build on?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Nagios, which is commonly used (thus well documented and support in the net is available) and open source.

Details for connecting your Jira instance to the monitoring can be found here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/57772/jira-monitoring-with-nagios

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider Naemon, which would be compatible with the mentioned article above, just a better UI and more active development.
http://www.naemon.org